# Bypass Autodiscover step

Tags: exchange, outlook, autodiscovery

**Question**

How can I bypass the step where the Autodiscover service of Microsoft Outlook checks for settings at `https://domain.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml`?

**Context**

Hi guys!

By default, Outlook sequentially checks for Autodiscover configuration services in [five default locations](http://enterpriseit.co/microsoft-exchange/outlook-autodiscover-order/); the second of such locations is `https://domain.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml`. This location is checked even before `autodiscover.domain.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml`.

A client of ours for which we manage a website at `domain.com` uses a remote Enterprise Exchange server at `outlook.com`. In principle, when his Outlook client automatically looks for Autodiscover settings at `https://domain.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml`, it shouldn't find anything, and move on to the next step, `autodiscover.domain.com`, which is correctly configured at the DNS level to point to `autodiscover.outlook.com`. However, the client does find some settings and fail; these settings turned out to be those of our hosting provider for `domain.com`, which are different from the desired settings at `outlook.com`.

We asked our web hosting provider to remove the URL `https://domain.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml`, but they refused. The reason is that `domain.com` resides on a shared machine, and cPanel only allows to disable the Autodiscover service server-wide. That is, it is not possible to remove the problematic URL for just one domain; I found out that this happens to be a [well-known limitation of cPanel](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/4099e289-55bf-476b-a9c4-ee1377046df7/cpanel-autodiscover-conflict-with-exchange?forum=exchangesvrgeneral).

Could you please suggest a workaround for this perfect storm? Ideally, I would prefer a server-side solution, but at this point even a client-side registry hack would be welcome. I have found some on Server Fault, but none dealt with this step of the Autodiscover logic.

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: You can control Autodiscover behavior with Group Policy if the client machines are domain joined or you can use the Registry if they're not. - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2612922 - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2212902

Comment: Thank you for your comment @joeqwerty! Do yo think it would be possible to apply a domain-wide Group Policy without having to configure each single email client? I would like to avoid having to configure each device in the organisation manually.

Comment: The first link in my comment is about disabling one or more methods via Group Policy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not ideal, but a workaround is via registry on the client computers.
(of course you may set this trough Group Policy)

In keys :

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\x.0\Outlook\AutoDiscover
```

and

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\x.0\Outlook\AutoDiscover
```

Note x.0 in the above registry path corresponds to the Outlook version (16.0 = Outlook 2016, 15.0 = Outlook 2013, 14.0 = Outlook 2010, 12.0 = Outlook 2007).

create the value :

```
ExcludeHttpsRootDomain
```

and set it to 1

Source en more information here :

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2212902

Comment: It should be noted that this will only fix Outlook clients, and only Windows ones at that.  Mobile devices will still require valid Autodiscover, or a deployed configuration profile through MDM to function properly.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I would definitely upvote it if I had enough reputation. @blaughw, would your solution (deployed configuration profile through MDM) work with a hosted Exchange server? Does it require to register each device or is it automatically applied to any device in the domain? Thank you :-)

Comment: Mail configuration will be different between Apple and Android devices.  Each MDM (Mobile Device Management) platforms is a bit different.  If this is a requirement for you, I would recommend doing more research here.  Pushing a configuration profile is a step to simplify connections for end-users.  This is definitely possible for Hosted Exchange, as along as the service is available from the internet.

Comment: I ended up moving the the domain on a dedicated server where I could disable cPanel's Autodiscover service. Expensive, but fast and effective :-) Thank you all for your input! I accept JFL's question because it gives a way to solve the problem, although not an ideal one, and it mentions Group Policy.